# Resubmitted paper not processed for 3 weeks. Should I notify the editor?

Tags: paper-submission

My paper was given a minor revision by a Springer journal. I finished the revision and submitted 3 weeks ago. But the paper still has not been sent to review nor accepted. Should I notify the editor or should I just wait longer?

Comment: Leave it alone.  Editors and reviewers are volunteer.  They process/review a paper when they are 'free', which could be the next hour, or the next year.

Comment: why are you so impatient?  The editor deals with 10s if not 100s of papers in a year, and they have a life outside of the journal.

Comment: The editors are not volunteers. They are employees of the journal. @Prof. Santa Claus

Comment: The reviewers haven't yet acknowledged the receival of your rebuttal letter and corrected manuscript. Springers computer system will start nagging them soon, no need for you to nag the editor.

Comment: @andy90 most editors receive no salary or benefits from the journals, unless they are chief editors.  (There are exceptions, such as Nature Publishing groups).  There are managing editors or handling editors that work for the journal but they are not usually academics and usually don’t deal with sending manuscripts to referees.

Comment: @andy90 in my discipline, all editors and reviewers are volunteers!!!!